# Mypy get attr-defined & name-defined error when use protobuf

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers, mypy

I use protobuf in my code and generated a py file using the command: `protoc --python_out=. samples/msg.proto`, my proto file is:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message MsgPackage
{
  message Msg
  {
    uint32 code = 1;
    string msg = 2;
  }

  repeated Msg messages = 1;
}
```

| Package | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Python | 3.11.2 |
| mypy | 1.0.1 |
| protobuf | 4.22.0 |

[image]

The [Python protocol buffer compiler](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/pythontutorial/#protobuf-api) doesn’t generate data access code directly, it create type dynamic. So executing the type check by mypy will get some errors:
[image]

How do I resolve the error like:  `Name "MsgPackage.Msg" is not defined`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use images when copying-and-pasting text is trivial. Text is better than images because (a) it enables others to reuse your code; (b) will likely outlive the image.

To answer your question, the reason is that you're not correctly using repeated fields.

Here's a solution that uses repeated fields to both create and output a `MsgPackage`:

```py
from google.protobuf.internal.containers import RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer

from msg_pb2 import MsgPackage


# See print(type(m.messages) below
def show_msg(msgs: RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer[MsgPackage.Msg]) -> None:
    print(msgs)


# With Python, once you create the root Message, child messages
# e.g. `MsgPackage.Msg` are constructed automatically
m = MsgPackage()

# In this case, because `messages` is a repeated field of type `Msg`
# One (!) solution is to use `add` to add items
# Another solution is to use `extend`
x = m.messages.add()
x.code = 5
x.msg = "Hello"

print(m)

print(len(m.messages))

# It's common to iterate over repeated fields
for i in m.messages:
    print(f"{i.code}: {i.msg}")

# RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer
print(type(m.messages))

show_msg(m.messages)
```

See the [Protobuf](https://protobuf.dev) documentation for an explanation of how to use Python [repeated](https://protobuf.dev/reference/python/python-generated/#repeated-fields) fields.

Here's the API documentation for [`google.protobuf.internal.containers`](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/internal/containers.html)

> **NOTE** You can generate PYI files using `protoc` too. These are often used by editors to provide type-checking of `protoc`-generated Python code:
>
> `protoc --python_out=${PWD} --pyi_out=${PWD} msg.proto`